Paramaterization of the Normal Distribution in Hypothesis Testing
When looking at how a z-statistic fits into the normal distribution $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi} } e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}$ my intuition was always that it was just the exponential $(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$.
However, according to this post:
Why are there two formulas for the z-test? It makes it abundantly clear that you should always use the standard error of the mean.
So my confusion is then is the normal distribution when being used in hypothesis testing replacing $\sigma$ with $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$? To say this another way when doing hypothesis testing would it be $f(x; u, \sigma)$ where $\sigma$ ~  $\sigma / \sqrt{n}$?

The term "standard error", used by itself, can be confusing, because it is actually unclear what it is referring to. It really should be "standard error of a statistic"; standard error of the mean, of the median, of the standard deviation, etc. That "standard error of the statistic" is really the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of that statistic. Which, intuitively makes sense; when interested in the possible dispersion of a statistic, you should use the standard deviation of the distribution of that statistic (not the standard deviation of the population from which you took the sample). You can check this paper, which goes over the estimators of various common statistics (mean, median, skewness, standard deviation, etc.), shows the formulas, and evaluates how good a job they do.
So there is really not one standard error; there are as many as on can come up with statistics of interest. Whereas the term "standard deviation" tends to be reserved for the population(s) from which you drew your sample(s). And a standard error is a standard deviation (of a sampling distribution).
When performing a hypothesis test, you use the standard error of the statistic you are interested in; so for a z-test, you use the standard error of the mean, which is $\frac {\sigma} {\sqrt n}$. But say that you are interested in a prediction interval (for the next datapoint to be drawn), then you would use the standard deviation of the population, $\sigma$, which is the standard error of the "next value".
Then, to obtain a CI of the statistic of interest, you generally multiply the estimate of the s.e. of the statistic by the critical values from the proper (standardized) sampling distribution of that statistic (e.g. z for mean, or prediction interval, if you know $\sigma$ of the population, or Student's t if the population standard deviation is not known).

First thank you for taking the time to answer. When finding confidence intervals we multiple the CV by the statistic (z in this case I want to assume we know σ
) but does that then mean the normal distribution from which we are pulling probability is characterized by the mean and standard error? In other words if I was doing this in R: x_bar <- 2 u <- 1 sigma <-1 n <- 100 2 * (1 - pnorm(x_bar, u, sigma / sqrt(n))

CV as in Coefficient of Variability? sd/mean? CV has nothing to do here? And sorry about your R code, but I am not able to understand what you were trying to say.

critical value - apologies and ignore the R code I think that just obfuscated what I was trying to clarify. Moving on... For example, if I wished to integrate the pdf to calculate the pvalue for a given test statistic (using the z statistic here) I would need to know the sigma of the CDF (for the normal distribution). Would I use the SE or the standard deviation?

Neither. If you want to know the p-value of the mean, you would use the s.e., and the critical value. To integrate the PDF (to get the CDF), you need the PDF of the population. The CDF gives you the critical values.
